# How to get data from jquery form builder if there are multiple form initialized on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I have a code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example formBuilder</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="build-wrap"></div>
<div class="build-wrap"></div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $(document.getElementsByClassName('build-wrap')).formBuilder();
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If it was initialized by id, then I could have get data with something like this:

```
  var fbEditor = document.getElementById('build-wrap');
  var formBuilder = $(fbEditor).formBuilder();

  document.getElementById('getJSON').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(formBuilder.actions.getData('json'));
  });
```

However, I am using classname to initialize form builder. Is there any way, when click on save, get the respective form-builder data? I am using https://formbuilder.online/

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xycvbj3r/3/

#PS: there could be numerous form builder inside php loop.

Comment: Hi, here `save` button is the button which `formbuilder` gives or it is custom button ?

Comment: Don't think you can do it with same class name as selector. Each form editor should be initialized seperately so you can access its instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
formBuilder.actions.getData('json');
```

Or:

```
formBuilder.actions.getData();
```

The live demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dreambold/q0tfp4yd/10/

Comment: Not sure, if you understand my question, you are just using single form and initializing based on id. Since, I have already mentioned that there will be multiple form on loop, so not sure, if that solves my problem.

Comment: What are you going to do with multiple forms? Are you going to submit the multi forms at a time? Please clarify your purpose for using multiple forms. So I can give you the best solution

Comment: no, not submitting all at once, there are around 10 forms on a page, and each question might have different, form fields, user will go to one question, select fields, and save data, and then again go to new question, select fields, and save it and so on.

Comment: Then why don't you submit the form individually?

Comment: Please show the example, that's all I needed. Create two form, submit them individually, and render them on their own. And, yes, I need multiple questions on the page, not one form builder per page.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue too. This worked for me

```js
var list = ['#ins1', '#ins2', '#ins3'];
          var instances = [];
          
          var init = function(i) {
            if (i < list.length) {
              var options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]));
                  $(list[i]).formBuilder(options).promise.then(function(res){
                console.log(res, i);
                instances.push(res);
                i++;
                init(i);
              });
            } else {
              return;
            }
            
          };
          init(0);
```

And to get data, you can use instances[key].actions.getData()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are planning to save this data, but to help with your problem of getting form data for a particular form you can use something like this

```js
var formBuilder = $(document.getElementsByClassName('build-wrap')).first().data('formBuilder').actions.getData()
```

Or to use it over a jQuery Collection then

```js
$(document.getElementsByClassName('build-wrap')).each(function () {
    var formBuilder = $(this).data('formBuilder').actions.getData()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback mentioned in the documentation, [onsave](https://formbuilder.online/docs/formBuilder/options/onSave/) which runs on editor save. So, when clicking on any form builder's save button, the respected form's data can be received.

Here is the code-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example formBuilder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="build-wrap"></div>
    <div class="build-wrap"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($) {
        var options = {
          onSave: function(evt, formData) {
            // This is the respected form's data
            console.log('MY DATA_________', formData)
          },
        };
        $(document.getElementsByClassName('build-wrap')).formBuilder(options); 
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle (couldn't create a working snippet due to not working CDNs.
)- https://jsfiddle.net/nehasoni988/rpo1jnuk/1/#&togetherjs=Mka9TJ4cex